# What is a word meaning a formal denouncement from the Pope?

Tags: single-word-requests, religion

As above, I'm looking for a word meaning something similar a formal denouncement from the Pope (or Church)?

Comment: Since you've tagged this as a single word request, you should include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used.

Comment: If there is an answer to this question it will be a *Latin* word.  The question is off topic in these parts.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark not necessarily. A Latin loanword could be adopted in English, and the related "excommunicate" demonstrates the that similar concepts do have English words

Comment: The answer cited ("classifying ... as sin") is not relevant to this question.

Comment: @guest: is it a person who is being denounced?

Comment: There are m any different varieties of papal or church denouncements, even if we limit it to Catholic religion. There is individual excommunication, or various lesser shunnings, like not being allowed to take communion. There are national decrees like the interdict, which applies to legal entities and their rulers and residents. When an interdict is in effect, no Mass may be celebrated, and no other sacraments, by anyone within the boundaries. In a Catholic region an interdict is intended to turn the residents against the rulers (who were likely to have offended the pope).

Comment: @JohnLawler, why don't you post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 6):

**Anathema**

> 2 a : a ban or curse solemnly pronounced by ecclesiastical authority and accompanied by excommunication

[Merrian-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anathema)

Comment: An example is Clement XI [Unigenitus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unigenitus) **papal bull** condemning and anathemizing  most principles of Jansenist theology.

Answer (score 0):

***Excommunication***:

> the action of officially excluding someone from participation in the sacraments and services of the Christian Church.
>
> - *"he appealed against the papal sentence of excommunication"*

(Oxford Languages)

Answer (score 0):

A formal letter to all Catholic churches, although not necessarily a denouncement, is an *[Encyclical](https://www.simplycatholic.com/what-is-an-)*.

Such letters provide guidance and clarification of spiritual matters.

Answer (score 0):

In catholocism a *[Papal Bull](https://www.britannica.com/topic/bull-papal)* is an edict from the Pope that defines the dogma of the religion.

These have often been sources of controversy through history.  For example, the several [Bulls surrounding Henry VIII of England and his relations with the Papacy](https://blog.nationalarchives.gov.uk/anglo-papal-relations-henry-viii-break-with-rome/) or the Bull that [denounced contraception as murder](http://churchandstate.org.uk/2021/01/the-catholic-church-and-contraception/#:%7E:text=Early%20opposition%20to%20contraception%20was%20often%20a%20reaction,%28papal%20bull%20by%20Pope%20Sixtus%20V%20in%201588%29.).

The Bull is named after the *Bulla*, or seal that is applied to the document.
It is the origin of the phrase *"a load of bull"* which was coined by English Protestants as a show of defiance to catholocism.

Comment: Both words that you have proposed are far more general than what the question is about.